# Why has BGProcessingTask already been registered?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am creating my own background task and I keep getting an error stating: 'Launch handler for task with identifier "processingTaskId" has already been registered'. I am still learning and would like to understand this error more.

`code`

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import BackgroundTasks  

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
let processingTaskId = "com.demo.processingtask"
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
   
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: processingTaskId, using: nil) { task in
            self.handleTask(task: task as! BGProcessingTask)
        }
    }
    
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
 }
 @available(iOS 13.0, *)
 func handleTask(task: BGProcessingTask) {
    scheduleTask() 
    
    task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
 }
 @available(iOS 13.0, *)
 func scheduleTask() {
    let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: processingTaskId)
    
    request.earliestBeginDate = nil
    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
    } catch {
        print("Could not schedule task: (error)")
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there's some weird edge case in which your background task does absolutely nothing but schedule another background task and then immediately terminate. I'd try (a) deferring the call to `setTaskCompleted` to simulate actually doing something in your background task; and (b) adding some minimal `earliestBeginDate` (say 5 minutes or whatever). See if either of those changes the behavior. I'd also search the codebase to make sure there isn’t some call to `register(forTaskWithIdentifier:using:launchHandler:)` lingering about elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Any direction is helpful, I'll give those a try.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error disappeared when I renamed the taskIdentifier.